# Laravel Blade Display Error Message with Asterisk and Variable Index

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have a form with dynamically generated fields. I validated them. I want to display the error messages.

```
protected $rules = [
       'orderLines.*.item_id' => 'required|exists:items,id'
]
```

Validation works fine. I get error messages which I am able to show as follows:

```
                @error('orderLines.*.item_id')
                <span class="text-red-600 text-sm" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
```

Asterisk displays errors for item_id of all lines at once. I want to display for only that one instance. Which I can by passing an absolute index value such as

```
                @error('orderLines.0.item_id')
                <span class="text-red-600 text-sm" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
```

I don't want to replace the * with absolute values such as 0 or 1 or 2. Instead, I have a running index and I want to use the index variable. How to do it? Tried the following. it does not work.

```
            @error('orderLines.{$index}.item_id')
            <span class="text-red-600 text-sm" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you do something like
 `@error("orderLines.{$index}.item_id")<span class="text-red-600 text-sm" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror`

Comment: the only difference between this and what I tried is the quotes. I tried single-quotes and you said double-quotes. It worked. Can you explain how they differ please?

Comment: basically its variable interpolation, a straight forward way of concatenating variables in between strings. Also can you mark the answer as approved and up vote it?